# поиск подстроки в строке с++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите дописать код, чтобы выходило из программы , при нахождении подстроки "END" в введенной строке.

Comment: Код лучше вставлять в сообщение текстом, а не изображением.

Comment: во-первых, надо формировать строку (а не только считать кол-во символов). Во-вторых - [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну собственно говоря вот:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // создаем массив с гласными буквами
    char *s = "AEIOUYaeiouy";
    // определяем начальное значение счетчика
    int n = 0;
    // строка(массив) в которой будем что-то считать
    char *str = "Stack Overflow"; 

    // проходимся по массиву циклом вайл
    while(*str)
    {
        // каждую буквы строки сверяем с массивом гласных букв
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {   
            // если нашли инкрементом увеличиваем счетчик
            if(*str==s[i]) n++;
        }
        //сдвигаем указатель на слудующий элемент массива
        str++;
    }
    // вывод роезультата
    cout << n << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```